# Open Google Maps app and display turn-by-turn navigation inside flutter webview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, flutter, webview

I want to display the Google Maps app with turn-by-turn navigation inside my flutter app.

I'm developing a Flutter application that can schedule routes, monitor the progression of the driver (in the background) and be able to reschedule the routes based on user input (e.g. a road block). I want to display an appbar in the bottom with info about the progression and some buttons to start or notify the app of a roadblock. Above this bar I want a window displaying turn-by-turn navigation based on the current part of the schedule. I want all of this to run automatically to reduce the amount of user input to the bare minimum (because the users are driving).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Madrid,Spain&origin=Barcelona,Spain&waypoints=Zaragoza|Huesca&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: Text('Dashboard'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I was able to set up a WebView with this example url:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Madrid,Spain&origin=Barcelona,Spain&waypoints=Zaragoza|Huesca&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate

It shows the Google Maps webapp with the desired route and a "navigate" button. However, when I press the navigate button, an net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME is dropped because it wants to fire an intent. I have a feeling that even when I'll be able to tackle this error, I will only be able to open the turn-by-turn navigation on a new screen/page instead of embedded inside the WebView (or somewhere else in my app).

Is this even possible or am I wasting my time trying to figure out a way to make this work?

Comment: As for now, we've started using Sygic (which is based on HERE Maps). Google has a Navigation SDK but it isn't being published any time soon. It's being used by Waze and Uber.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I am stuck in similar kind of situation

Comment: Hi Sarthak! There are 2 sides to this question: 1) Turn-by-turn on a mobile device and 2) An app within an app (potentially with Webview). For now we're still working hard on this project and turned from Flutter to plain Java Android. We weren't able to get an app within an app and we also weren't able to get turn-by-turn navigation from Google. Sygic did not meet our business requirements (even though they advertised otherwise so beware!) so we explored other providers like MapBox and BeNav. Now our app fires an intent to open another navigation app starting navigation of a precomputed route.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to force turn-by-turn Google Maps navigation inside a WebView. Also, using Google Maps API within your app to create your own turn-by-turn navigation may also breach [Google Maps Platform's Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) - see 3.2.3.d: 'No Re-Creating Google Products or Feature.'

What I can suggest is to let other apps handle the intent being broadcasted to launch an external maps app to handle the navigation. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64653991) on how you can filter intent URLs and let them be handled externally.