Webpage not available. The webpage at tel:1000 could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
i'm building a mobile app using phoenix framework, i want when the user press on the call number button it dials that number.
what i tried:

 <a class="text-zinc-900 text-sm font-medium" href="tel:10000" target="_blank"><%= gettext("10000") %></a>

 <a class="text-zinc-900 text-sm font-medium" href="tel:10000""><%= gettext("10000") %></a


3. <a onclick="window.open('tel:10000')" class="external">10000</a>

 <button class ="bg-red-500" id="dial_button" phx-hook="Dial" >Call 10000</button>
and in the javascript file
`const Dial ={
mounted(){
const call = document.getElementById("dial_button")
call.addEventListener("click", function(){        
         window.location.href = "tel:10000";
})

}
}
export default Dial;`


please if you have any ideas how can I do it with a different approach please advise me.

There is nothing wrong with the link per se; href="tel:..." is the correct to link to a telephone number. I don't know what your "phoenix-framework" does, but I would guess that it perhaps interferes with the link clicks, and tries to "fetch" the URL in the background using AJAX ...? Then you'll need to find a way to make it not do that for such tel: links.

Possible workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285689/neterr-unknown-url-scheme-error-when-url-isintent-kakaopay

You can simplify your current phx-hook implementation for dialing the number. Here’s a cleaner version: Call 10000

I tried the above but sadly it also didn't work still gives me the same error, is there any other way other than the tel: ,  window.open or window.location

Are you testing this on your phone and what browser are you using?

I'm testing on Android emulator in android studio
